# Bundling textAngular and angular-sanitize with webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack, textangular

I'm currently in the process of migrating a project (ng 1.5.8) from gulp pipeline to webpack.
I'm facing an issue where textAngular gives me the following error message `Module 'ngSanitize' is not available`.
if I add a `require('angular-sanitize')` before the `require('textangular')` then I get the following error message `The textAngular-sanitize provider has been replaced by another -- have you included angular-sanitize by mistake?`
I've tried playing with the externals of my webpack config with no luck so far. I've also tried using angular-module-sanitize, didn't work either.
So here is my question: how can I configure properly webpack + my requires so textAngular has the proper dependencies provisionned? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finnaly got it to work.
The solution is to:
- not require angular-sanitize
- not do anything special to the webpack config
- use these lines to require text angular instead (the generic one was including to much stuff)
`require('../../node_modules/textangular/dist/textAngular-sanitize.min');
require('../../node_modules/textangular/dist/textAngular.umd');`